# De Morgan's Law - Proof of $(\cup_{i} A_{i})^c = (\cap_{i} A_{i}^c)$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I would appreciate it if I could get some feedback on my attempt to proof De Morgan's Law. That is, if it is correct or if there is a better way to do this proof. I am self-studying probability theory from Grimmett and Stirzaker's book Probability and Random Processes and am going through the exercises. Thanks in advance.

Let ${A_i : i \in I}$ be a collection of sets.

$(\cup_{i} A_{i})^c = (A_1 \cup A_2 \cup A_3 \cup A_4 \ldots)^c$
$= (A_1 \cup A_2)^c \cup (A_3 \cup A_4)^c \cup \dots$
$= (A_{1}^c \cap A_{2}^c) \cup (A_{3}^c \cap A_{4}^c)\ldots$
$=(A_{1}^c \cap A_{2}^c \cap A_{3}^c \cap A_{4}^c \ldots)$
$=\cap_{i} A_{i}^c$

Comment: How'd you prove that $$\left(A_1\cup A_2\cup B\right)^c=(A_1\cup A_2)^c\cup B^c\;\;??$$

Comment: It's not correct. Your second equality is invalid. Prove by showing each side is a subset of the other. (In one direction: "Let $x$ be an element of the LHS. Do stuff using the definitions... So $x$ is an element of the RHS")

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perhaps simpler by definition:

$$x\in\left(\bigcup_i A_i\right)^c\iff x\notin\bigcup_i Ai\iff\;\forall\,i\;,\;x\notin A_i\iff$$

$$\iff \;\forall\,i\,,\;x\in A_i^c\iff x\in\bigcap_i A_i^c$$

Comment: I follow the reasoning here up to the last "iff". Please can you expand on that.

Comment: @IftikharKhan, an element belongs to the *intersection* of some sets iff it belongs to each one of them (=to all of them)...

Comment: Got it! This is a really nice proof.

Comment: I am really bad with these types of questions (I come from an applied maths background). What is the best way to improve one's ability in this area in your opinion?

Comment: Get the heck out of applied mathematics at once! Just kidding: try to follow 1-2 books on the subject (set theory, discrete mathematics) that appeal to you and do exercises there...

Comment: @DonAntionio, is my proof correct here: $x\in\left(\bigcap_i A_i\right)^c  \Leftrightarrow x\notin\bigcap_i Ai \Leftrightarrow\;\exists\,i\;,\;x\notin A_i \Leftrightarrow\;\exists\,i\;,\;x\in A_i^c \Leftrightarrow\;x \in \left(\bigcup_i A_i^c\right)$

Comment: Yes it is, @IftikharKhan ...

Comment: @DonAntonio why induction cannot be used to prove this , in case of infinite number of sets ?

Comment: @ReadThyOwnBook Because such a proof would only apply for a set of sets indexed by a well-ordered set, and even then, if the indexing set is not the natural numbers, only by making some adjustments.